# loading 3d text of different language other than English in A-frame

Tags: aframe

I've been working on my web VR project with A-frame, and I'm having a trouble with 3d text.

I'm trying to load Korean and Japanese text, but only numbers or alphabets were visible, and all the other texts in Korean and Japanese are not appearing.

I first thought it's because the basic fonts are all for English, so I used hiero to create custom font with Korean font and using it. > but still not working.

Can anybody guess what the problem is, and come up with a solution?

Comment: sure we could try and _guess_ based on this description, but what would be the point? We could be here all week. If you show your code and explain the problem in sufficient detail (better than "not working" I mean) then someone might actually be able to _know_ what the problem is. I suspect you might find that a lot more useful.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create an MSDF version of the font you want to use. [This GitHub repo](https://github.com/etiennepinchon/aframe-fonts/) has a large collection of fonts, but (currently) only in latin character sets. I would subscribe for updates on [aframe-fonts#1](https://github.com/etiennepinchon/aframe-fonts/issues/1) or try to build an MSDF font yourself to use Korean characters in A-Frame. I'm not familiar with creating those fonts, but [generate.js](https://github.com/etiennepinchon/aframe-fonts/blob/master/generate.js) or searching around may get some results. Best of luck!